# How to properly restore settings when running a script using "source"?

Tags: bash, script, bash-scripting

I'm writing a script that needs to be executed using `source`, because its task is to modify the environment. During the script, I want to use `set -e` so that any error stops the script. The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
# do something
cd somewhere
source anotherScript
```

The problem is that `set -e` naturally remains in effect after the script finishes. How can I ensure that the altered `set` option is properly restored to its prevous value when the script stops (in any way - either by completing successfully or on an error)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528624/how-to-restore-previous-set-x-option-in-bash

Comment: The same issue (for the `-x` / `xtrace` option)  is addressed at [Suppress execution trace for echo command?](https://superuser.com/q/806599/150988#1141026)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly the same way you activate it: calling the buitin `set`:

```
$ set -o errexit
$ set -o | grep errexit
errexit         on
$ set +o errexit
$ set -o | grep errexit
errexit         off
```

From the `bash(1)` manpage, under the `SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS` section, `set' command:

```
-o option-name
The option-name can be one of the following:
    errexit Same as -e.
```

Comment: Is there a way how to save (all) these settings and restore them later?

Comment: Run `set -o` to known your current setup. Be explicit when setting/unsetting any of them on your scripts.

Answer (score 17):

The command `set +o` lists the current settings as commands that restore the same state, e.g.

```
$ set +o
set +o allexport
set -o braceexpand
set -o emacs
set +o errexit
set +o errtrace
...
```

You can easily restore all the options later, if you save this output to a shell variable:

```
SAVED_OPTIONS=$(set +o)
set -e
# do something
eval "$SAVED_OPTIONS"
```

Bash includes also a number of non-standard (not POSIX) options that are adjusted using `shopt` command. The command `shopt -p` can be used to save these options in a similar fashion.

If you only want to save and restore one option, you can use the $- environment variable, which lists the current set of options as letters, e.g.

```
$ echo $-
himBH
```

You could use something like this to save and restore a particular option:

```
[[ $- = *e* ]]
SAVED_ERREXIT=$?
set -e
# do something
(( $SAVED_ERREXIT )) && set +e
```

Comment: Note that it's very important not to miss the quotes around "$SAVED_OPTIONS" in the eval call.

Answer (score 3):

## Use a RETURN trap

`RETURN` traps work for sourced scripts, too.

> Commands specified with an `RETURN` trap are executed before execution resumes after a shell function or a shell script executed with `.` or `source` returns.
>
> – https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html

**main_script.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "inside main script"
shopt -o errexit
source a_script_to_be_sourced.sh
echo "back inside main script"
shopt -o errexit
```

**a_script_to_be_sourced.sh**

```
trap "$(shopt -p -o errexit)" RETURN
set -e # Equivalents: set -o errexit; shopt -s -o errexit
echo "inside sourced script"
shopt -o errexit
```

**Test**

```
$ ./main_script.sh 
inside main script
errexit         off
inside sourced script
errexit         on
back inside main script
errexit         off
```

Answer (score 2):

Restoring previous **activated** settings can be quickly done as:

```
PREV_SETTING=$-  # e.g. himxBH  (there was xtrace)

set +x
# do your script without xtrace, ...

set -$PREV_SETTING
```

The other way around (restore to the off state) AFAIK there isn't such a shortcut and Seppo's answer covers all cases.

Comment: Your code as written yields `-bash: set: -i: invalid option` because the `-i` flag notes an interactive shell.